# Floating Action Button Border Color is not changing

Tags: android, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

I changed the `Floating Action Button` backgroundTintList color by using the following code:

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(mResources.getColor(R.color.fab_color)));
```

But I end up getting the following on API 4.4.2:

[image]

Everything looks fine on API 21 <= but anything below API 21, I have this problem for the FAB.

I am programmatically creating the FAB like so:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    fab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = mResources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
    ((CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)).addView(fab);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
    p.setAnchorId(R.id.appBarLayout);
    p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
    fab.setLayoutParams(p);
    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(mResources.getColor(R.color.fab_color)));
    fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_button));
```

I also happened to run by the official [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/b41126e51e80ad409c86599999e68d7b640e96d3/design/lollipop/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java#L54) for the `FloatingActionButton` and I saw that they are instantiating a borderDrawable here:

```
 @Override
void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable originalBackground, ColorStateList backgroundTint,
        PorterDuff.Mode backgroundTintMode, int rippleColor, int borderWidth) {
    // Now we need to tint the original background with the tint
    mShapeDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalBackground.mutate());
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(mShapeDrawable, backgroundTint);
    if (backgroundTintMode != null) {
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(mShapeDrawable, backgroundTintMode);
    }

    final Drawable rippleContent;
    if (borderWidth > 0) { // BORDER DRAWABLE RIGHT HERE!!
        mBorderDrawable = createBorderDrawable(borderWidth, backgroundTint);
        rippleContent = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{mBorderDrawable, mShapeDrawable});
    } else {
        mBorderDrawable = null;
        rippleContent = mShapeDrawable;
    }

    mRippleDrawable = new RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(rippleColor),
            rippleContent, null);

    mShadowViewDelegate.setBackgroundDrawable(mRippleDrawable);
    mShadowViewDelegate.setShadowPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 29):

I ended adding:

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

this doesn't create borderDrawable and border is not visible.

Answer (score 6):

just change the coloraccent in styles file

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

add color which u want as your background color for FAB

EDIT:  okk.. well here is an alternative what you can do .. define this FAB in your xml

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_color"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and it will make changes and then you don't need to be do as programmatically.

Comment: I have other views in the app that must use a specific color accent so this option is a no go, and is not really scalable. This is more like a 'Nuclear' option and I would rather not do that.

Comment: This is not constructive.

Comment: @AndyRoid check once i added my another suggestion in answer

Comment: This is useless in relation to the question.

Answer (score 4):

To just change background color use: `app:backgroundTint="#4000FF00"`

Eg:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/xxxx"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#00FF00"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right"
        />
```

But if you want to make it transparent, use `app:elevation` and `app:pressedTranslationZ` property.

Eg:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/xxx"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#4000FF00"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right"
        />
```

Those properties are used to give view effect on click and elevation to button.

Comment: This works for borders!

The behavior of "android" and "app" in the namespace was different.
Setting it to app:backgroundTint changed the border color.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to change the colors programmatically in a backwards compatible way:

`DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(fab.getDrawable()), tintColor);` <- icon

`DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(fab.getBackground()), backgroundTintColor);` <- background

Answer (score 2):

Well I think some people still get this situation so It may help somenone

In attributes section there is two backgroundTint attributes second one is for

to change border color I think I hope it helps someone[image]